# Prevent Laravel from login a user after password reset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I would like to prevent Laravel from auto login users after a password has been reset through. I rather would like to redirect a user to the login form afterwards. Is that possible?

I guess the corresponding process is located in "ConfirmPasswordController". This controller contains the trait: "ConfirmsPasswords" which has

```
     /**
     * Confirm the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function confirm(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        $this->resetPasswordConfirmationTimeout($request);

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
                    : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

But I really don't want to make changes to a vendor trait. Any ideas of what to do here?

Again: I really just want a user to be redirected to the login form, after she / he has validated the password forgotten email and confirmed a new password for her / his account.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably `$this->redirectPath()` returns the path where to redirect user. Either modify this redirectPath function, or pass in login path directly to `redirect('/login')' or maybe try Auth::logout(); before returning.

Comment: As Suggested you must logout user before returning. this should solve the issue